How to select specific marker in MUI React Charts
I am trying to highlight specific markers on an MUI x react chart when a particular selection is made.
<ChartContainer
    width={500}
    height={500}
    series={[
             {
                data: [1,2,3,4,5,6,9,10]
                color: 'black',
                type: 'line',
             },
            ]}
     xAxis=[2001,2002,2004,2005,2006,2007,2008,2009,2010]
     >

     <LinePlot />
     <MarkPlot />
     <ChartsXAxis />
     <ChartsYAxis />
</ChartContainer>

I would like to be able to select a value represented on the X-axis, i.e. 2005, and have the marker at x:2005, y:5 be highlighted in red.
